# Books on data fraud detection?

Tags: references, fraud-detection

Do you have any good **book recommendations** on the topic of **detecting data manipulation and scientific fraud by statistical analysis** (or any other mathematical approach really)?

I see that there are many books on the topic of fraud detection in the context of finance and accounting, but I would like a book that gets into **the scientific perspective** (perhaps also including historical examples, like fraudulent data in biology or data that was badly manipulated in astrophysics and how these bad actors were discovered).

Comment: As I recall, [Freakonomics](https://freakonomics.com/books/#freakonomics) includes at least one chapter on detecting cheating on standardized tests.  It caught my interest because a substantial part of my consulting practice specializes in the statistical detection of cheating (and its opposite, statistical analysis of potentially invalid "detections" of cheating and fraud).

Comment: The Data Colada crew [have a few good examples with code](https://datacolada.org/archives/category/fake-data).

Comment: The classic statistical example of fraud is, of course, Benford's Law.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law

Comment: Having used outlier detection in targeting retail banks which were laundering cartel money, that's another avenue worth pursuing. There are no shortage of approaches to outlier analysis. In my case, it was based on k-means clustering and identifying bank branches which were way outside the norm in their behavior, *norm* defined as a cluster centroid.

Comment: Gelman posted a scientific fraud article on his blog  https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2023/11/19/dorothy-bishop-on-the-prevalence-of-scientific-fraud/