# What are some good books on how to avoid, as a statistician, being used to lend false credibility to a dishonest project?

Tags: references, ethics

I mean for example companies or organizations who are not really interested in decision making driven by serious data analysis, but who employ or hire statisticians to try to give false credibility to "results" that have already been decided before any serious data analysis has actually taken place. Another example could be a company tampering the data they provide to a statistician they hired, to try to make the company look good.

Are there references on how to deal with this kind of scenarios, for someone trying to do his job honestly without being manipulated?

I guess this is an issue that experts in many fields might have to face one day or another, but I was wondering if some references were tackling the issue specifically from the point of view of statisticians or data analysts/scientists.

Thank you.

--
Edit:

I'm not entirely sure why this question was closed. My question is general, the examples I give are just illustrations, perhaps not perfect. I don't have more specific examples in mind, and that's why I ask this question in the first place: if I already knew specifically how a statistician can be manipulated, I think I wouldn't need references on this subject. I think that ignorance of the details is one of the things that make someone vulnerable to manipulation.

In my opinion, this question can only be answered by people with a good knowledge of publications in the field, that's why my first thought was to ask it here (otherwise, I don't see where else I could ask it, but would be glad to get suggestions if my question stay closed).

Codes of conduct are interesting and definitely relevant, but I think that the thing they lack and I'm looking for are "case study" examples. So if you want, what I would find interesting is something a bit like a code of conduct aimed at statisticians, but with detailed real-life examples, and not just listing principles. Are there books like that?

--
Second edit:

As mentioned in the comment section, there's another question on a related topic  ([What are some good references on the history of ethics in statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631673/237901)). So I'm aware of the answers there. However I'm looking for something more specific, and directly relevant to today's practice (so references about historical case studies are of secondary interest to me, unless these past situations are likely to still happen today. I prefer to clarify that, in order to avoid possible duplicate answers with the other question, even if I think my question should be distinct enough).

Comment: 1st example: Hardly book-length, but the Royal Statistical Society's [Code of Conduct](https://rss.org.uk/about/policy-and-guidelines/code-of-conduct) is perhaps enough - I'm sure other professional societies have similar rules. Case studies: Graciela Bevacqua & Andreas Georgiou. 2nd example: See [Books on data fraud detection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/630651/17230). I don't think it's clear what else you'd consider as "this kind of scenario".

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks, that's interesting and also helpful to make my request more specific: codes of conduct have an element I'm definitely looking for, but I think they also lack a "case study" part, which is something I'm after. I added this element to the question, hopefully it will help reconsidering my question as in line with the website editorial policies. Otherwise maybe I'll try to ask my question on another website, but for the moment I hardly see where I could.

Comment: By the way, there's a minor bug with a link in the "closing message" at the top of my question (the first link is clickable, but the second one isn't, and it appears between brackets, which is a bit odd). I'm not sure where to report this, but here's a screenshot of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9RUc.jpg

Comment: Didn't we recently have the ethics in statistics question? [What are some good references on the history of ethics in statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631673/237901). This question seems to be about the same topic but in addition asks for a rule book on how to act in difficult situations. It won't be easy for sure.

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks, very relevant. I'm a bit embarrassed, because it quite overlaps with my own question indeed, but on the other hand my question is a bit more specific. I'm not sure I'll get different answers than those given in your link, though. Besides deleting my question, I'm not sure if there's something I can do to avoid a waste of effort from answerers (e.g. duplicate answers between this question and the other one).

Comment: @dipetkov If it can help relative to what to do with my question, I'm looking for books dealing with situations of today (so historical situations that couldn't happen today are of secondary interest to me).

Comment: Not writing as an answer because I haven't read it, but 'Bullshit Jobs' by David Graeber might fit the bill.  There was an article in Significance a few years ago on how it might relate to statisticians.  https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2019.01321.x

Comment: I agree with the re-opening; but I've made the q. 'community wiki', as we do with broad reference requests that solicit a list of suggestions rather than a single definitive answer.

Comment: Your question is not a duplicate and I didn't intend to suggest closing it. I enjoyed the pointers in the "Ethics in statistics" thread and wanted to advertise them here as well. The more stories (about statistics) the better, so I hope this questions gets good answers too.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Fascinating article, it describes exactly what I had in mind. Thanks. It's nice to see other people wondering about these issues. I'll have a go at Graeber's book, it sounds very relevant.

Comment: *"how to avoid, as a statistician, being used to lend false credibility to a dishonest project"* This is an interesting topic, but unlikely the *main* topic of a book. One book that relates to it is Huff's 'How to Lie with Statistics'. Ironically the writer was allegedly used by the tabacco industry to write a (never published) sequel 'How to Lie with Smoking Statistics' to represent the smoking industry favourably.